# Refresh Html layout to recalculate scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have a `div` with a fixed size which displays `scrollbars` because the content is too large. This is ok. My problem occurs when I resize the `div` in order to hide the `scrollbars`, I have to increase the size more than necessary to hide the `scrollbars`. This is because the `scrollbars` themselves occupy some space in the `div`. Is there a way to ask the browser to recalculate the size of the `div` and its inner content and see if there really should be a scrollable content or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery for DOM handling:

```
$("div#yourdiv").attr("overflow", "hidden"); <-- remove scrollbars
setTimeout(function(){
   $("div#yourdiv").attr("overflow", "auto"); // auto | initial
},1); <-- 1 millisecond is enough to allow the DOM to update
```

Comment: Did you mean css instead of attr, like $("div#yourdiv").css(...)?

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake and could arrange with:

```
$('body').attr('style', 'overflow: auto !important');
```